# GPS when flying over the ocean

Tags: air-travel, maps, gps-navigation

How can I see my location when flying over an ocean? I know that many airlines show you that on your screen, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do that on a phone, and without an internet connection.

Any OS is fine, Android, iOS, or even Windows Mobile.

I assume this won't be dangerous in any way as the phone would be on flight mode, and GPS is passive.

Comment: Does your phone (or tablet with GPS) has a world map connected to the GPS? If so, get a window seat, as farther from the windows GPS is often not working well.

Comment: @Willeke A world map no. Only limited areas. Google Maps doesn't let downloading an offline map of anywhere close to a transatlantic (US to UK) flight.

Comment: So the answers can/should include how to get the needed maps as well as which device to use. I usually use my route planner app but that does not include oceans either.

Comment: What do you mean by "see my location"?  The Compass app on iPhone will display your latitude and longitude.  Or do you mean you want to see it on a map?

Comment: @NateEldredge I mean see it on a map. But the map doesn't have to be exact. I don't need street names for example, just the general shorelines of origin and destination.

Comment: There are many apps using free offline maps based on the Open Street Map data. Why not simply use one of them?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Do you know if they include a way to download the data in a way that is non-prohibitive memory-wise and if they include oceans? (What app are you referring to specifically?)

Comment: I use my handheld GPS for that (Garmin GPSmap 62), it has a better antenna than smartphone GPS receivers.  When I hold it against the window, I usually get a fix, but it does take up to 5 minutes.  I've never been told off by cabin crew, and I can easily download the gpx later by mounting the device, for geolocating pictures.  I've found that the speed and altitude are quite accurate.

Comment: If you're looking for a software then it might be better suited on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: the **ocean** aspect is totally unrelated.  it is, simply, hard to get a GPS signal inside an aircraft.

Comment: **maps.me** is far and away the best and most popular "offline mapping GPS" for both apple/droid.   unfortunately, these days it does have ads but any search for such software starts with maps.me, it's far and away the most popular.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - your rhetorical question is not like you: that is precsely what the OP is asking and does not know about!  :O

Comment: @ispiro - click to download maps.me and start from there, see if you like it.  if you don't like it google "maps.me alternatives".  Enjoy!

Comment: With advanced GPS software you can preload the satelite almanac the day of travel which would help you get a fix more reliably. Almanac data is changed daily and transmitted continuously at a low bitrate so you need ~12 minutes of good visibility to get complete information, this is sometimes the reason it can be difficult to get a lock in environments with good visibility of small number of satellites, if you preload this data you can get a lock much quicker and with fewer satellites visible.

Comment: Good question, but... *why?* Just look at the in-flight screen. Or take a nap and don't worry about it... some hobbies are just plain weird.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use [OsmAnd](https://osmand.net/) for this sort of thing. There's a base world map that's not super detailed at the city level, but is certainly more than adequate for tracking the location of any passenger flight. It's also very helpful for having an accurate, detailed map of your destination before you even figure out how to get cell service after you land.

Comment: Thanks. From your answer I also conclude that the built in OS apps don't have this option. +1.

Comment: @ispiro, you just may to try [maps.me][1] offline map app. I used it in my latest flight. The map is based on OSM data too, but it's in vector.


  [1]: https://maps.me/download/

Comment: +1 but why pay for such a thing?  overwhelemingly people just use maps.me.  start with that, then search for (other) free alternatives, and then maybe pay for one

Comment: @Fattie: You don't have to pay for it, the free version is more than capable of tracking flights. It's good software, so I chose to support the developers.

Answer (score 34):

There are some things you have to be aware of. For example, you might think that it's enough to turn your GPS on, start your app, and see your position, as simply as that. Well, not really!

First of all, the plane shields from radio waves, so you are almost always forced to keep the phone next to (even *against*) the window to get your first fix. The farther you are from the window, the harder it is. After the first fix you can usually move a little, but it's hard to tell how much. Just try it. **This means you'd better book a window seat.**

Then, consider that there's a huge difference between a [cold, a warm and a hot start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix). "Cold" means that your GPS has no idea where the satellites are, because you haven't used it in many days, so it must get [the position of the satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris) from the satellites themselves, and they transmit it slowly. When you have a data connection the phone can normally download the data from the Internet (this would be "[Assisted GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)" or A-GPS), but on board a plane it's normally either not available or very expensive. So: **when you are still on the ground, start your GPS app and wait until you have a fix.** This will make everything faster (it's the so-called "warm" start).

One more disclaimer: [for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361870/android-how-to-get-accurate-altitude) the altitude measured by a GPS is not accurate at all. Once I compared it with the one shown by the plane's infotainment system, and the difference was more than 500 metres (!!!). It probably doesn't matter, but you might want to know it.

Now the bad part: GPS receivers can be *very* different from each other, and they can have unexpected problems.

- My first phone with integrated GPS used a receiver ([SiRFstarIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SiRFstarIII)) that was top-notch at the time (10 years ago!), and I think I managed to see my position 20% of the times. All the other times it was an eternal wait... The receiver was simply not good enough.
- Then I switched to a phone which used a [NovaThor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NovaThor) chip. For some reason I've never understood, it worked until the plane reached an altitude of 3950 metres, and then it suddenly stopped working. It had nothing to do with speed, it was just the height. I guess it was some kind of restriction put in place to avoid that the chip could be used to guide missiles, or something like that. Go figure. Anyway, if you happen to have a phone with such restrictions, you are out of luck. And I think the only way to find it out is trying.
- My current phone uses a [Snapdragon 625 chipset](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-625-mobile-platform), and guess what? Altitude is not a problem, but there are others! Quite often it "gets lost": for some reason you start seeing the altitude increasing very slowly (like a couple of metres every 10 seconds), until it finally hangs. Sometimes it helps to close the app and restart it, but it isn't guaranteed.

And all these phones have always worked perfectly when used in a car or on foot, which is what they are designed for. Apparently, the poor reception due to the plane's shielding, combined with the high speed and altitude, gives GPS receivers a hard time. **And I don't think there's a way to know how good your GPS will work on a plane, apart from trying it.**

Finally, the apps. On Android I use [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest). It's free, and it's great for getting the coordinates, altitude and speed, but it doesn't have maps. To see where I am I normally use [TomTom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomtom.gplay.navapp) with offline maps, which is also free as long as you don't use it to get directions. But obviously the maps don't cover the oceans, so you need something else.

Comment: Actually GPS reception is BETTER inside the aircraft at altitude comparing to inside a car, for example. It is possible to get reception even in the middle of the aircraft. Tried myself.

Comment: I didn't know anyone had blocked GPS at that low an altitude.  You're right, it's manufacturers not wanting their chips to be used for missile guidance.  They also put speed limits on them but those are normally above jetliner speeds.

Comment: The display in the plane was probably showing pressure altitude if you were above 15,000 feet or so. It's not the same thing as actual AMSL.

Comment: The altitude in the infotainment system is not accurate either. It is taken from the barometric altimeter which is set to flight levels, not to altitudes according to local QNH. Notice how the autopilot holds whole thousands of feet. Those are flight levels - levels of constant pressure, NOT constant altitude. You will have a hard time verifying whether the infotainment or the GPS is closer to the actual altitude.

Comment: @hobbs Exactly, I didn't see your comment. Just note that the transition altitude varies widely from place to place (and is mostly below 10 000 ft in Europe).

Comment: Note that you need "to see" 4 GPS-satellites to calculate the correct altitude. One needs 3 for the place and the 4th for the height.

Comment: For me it varies based on which aircraft I'm on. E.g. I've never gotten a signal on a Boeing 737, while there's no problem on a Bombardier CRJ900 (to take some recent flights).

Comment: I wonder if the GPS software in consumer devices treats the results it gets at high altitudes as an error.

Comment: @GeorgeY. That's not true on most airliners. The frame is aluminum and blocks the signal quite well. It may work a little better on a 787 or A350 with carbon composite fuselage, but those still have a conductive layer that would act as a Faraday cage. They have this in order to protect the fuselage from lightning strikes. I've used GPS on planes many times and my experience is exactly as described in the answer: it takes forever to get an initial fix and requires being near a window.

Comment: @StrangerToKindness I've done it plenty of times on a 737, but I always get window seats and usually had to hold the phone to the window to get an initial fix.

Comment: @reirab I have done this myself many times. You may take longer to get the initial fix (or you can walk to and hang out for a bit near window to speed it up), but once you get the fix, you will have it even in the middle seats.

Comment: @georgey I've tried it myself too, and it works on some planes fine and others not at all, even when by the window and I was already using the GPS before boarding.

Comment: @VladimirF and hobbs: Thanks, I had no idea the altitude shown by the infotainment could be inaccurate!

Answer (score 3):

I use [maps.me](https://maps.me) for offline maps.

To be able to receive a GPS signal, I have to sit next to a window and push my phone against it. This sometimes works.

Answer (score 2):

I've used both [Here maps](https://wego.here.com/) and [maps.me](https://maps.me/) on the airplanes. It seems Here has much wider coverage. While you can't download maps of oceans, you can still see the real globe when zooming out and know where you are. That's the most important point compared to maps.me (which only zooms out to a world map instead of a globe that you can rotate around)

If you have plenty of space you can download maps for all the continents and get a much more detailed map including a lot of sea areas

[image]
[image]

Below are some of it in action

- https://youtu.be/PLPXhIWrRxk?t=109
- https://youtu.be/oqiDwICxFZo

Of course it'll be better if there's an offline Earth map. Unfortunately Google Earch doesn't support offline mode and the best you can do is viewing the area to cache it before the trip

- [Viewing Google Earth in offline mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63196/42635)
- [Use of google earth offline in an android device](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gec-open-forum/tkiecc2cjTE)

Answer (score 0):

While GPS is prohibited by many airlines, such as [United](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/inflight/devices.html), under a broader electronics ban, many/most travelers have GPS enabled inadvertently.

If you are one who has 'forgotten' to turn it off, any GPS app on the phone will give you a location...provided you can reliably receive the signals within the aircraft.

Also, you can see your location retroactively in many regions by using flight tracking services such as FlightAware.com.

Comment: You can use GPS in 'airplane' mode as your GPS receiver doesn't emit any electromagnetic waves.

Comment: As of a couple years ago, [airplane mode does not disable the GPS receiver on iOS devices](https://www.macobserver.com/analysis/ios-airplane-mode-gps-nfc/). Tens of thousands of people a day on United flights have phones that have their GPS receivers turned on, regardless of the rules and any theoretical potential for interference.

Comment: @user71659 Remember all those plane accidents that kept on happening because of LO and IF leakage? No, me neither...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88852/discussion-on-answer-by-johns-305-gps-when-flying-over-the-ocean).